# Should you use State when a component will Re-Render regardless due to a Props change?

Tags: reactjs

App.js:

```
class App extends React.Component {
  state = {
    pokemons: [
      { name: 'Charmander_Managed_By_State', level: 5 }
    ]
  }

  propsLevel = 5;

  levelPokemonHandler = () => {
    this.setState({
      pokemons: [
        { name: 'Charmander_Managed_By_State', level: (this.state.pokemons[0].level +1) }
      ]
    })
    this.propsLevel++;
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <h1>Hi, I'm a React App</h1>
        <button onClick={this.levelPokemonHandler}>Level Pokemon</button>
        <Pokemon name={this.state.pokemons[0].name} level={this.state.pokemons[0].level}/>
        <Pokemon name="Charmander_Managed_By_Props" level={this.propsLevel}/>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Pokemon.js

```
const pokemon = (props) => {
    return (
        <div>
            <p>I'm {props.name} and I'm level {props.level}</p>
            <p>{props.children}</p>
        </div>
    );
}
```

Given the code above, is changing the Pokemon level via state appropriate or not?
Since level will be passed as a property to the Pokemon component having it explicitly in state is redundant, but it does add some clarity.

What way is generally considered best practice?

Comment: Where in your example you passing/using props?

Comment: I'm sorry, I just updated the question with the Pokemon component that receives the props.

Answer (score 1):

In your first Pokemon component, since you are updating the prop for `level` that your Pokemon component is receiving, you really need to store it in state. That way your Pokemon component will re-render when you update state, thus getting the updated value of `this.state.pokemons[0].level` Otherwise simply iterating the constant value up for `this.propsLevel` wouldn't update.

The second way you've done it is static. Props passed will not update if state does.

In general, if you have something the user will update via interaction, you'd want to store in state so you can re-render with update data. If there's no interaction, you are fine with setting static props. Just realize they will be the same for the lifetime of the component.

Answer (score 0):

Both ways are fine and it's not like best practice here. Only thing is if Parent component also needs to be re-rendered on state change (may be because parent also has some part that depends on the state, some text or some other element), then you can keep internal state of parent and pass it to the child component.

And, if you don't need a re-render of any part of parent then you can simply use other way. Since, there is no `setState()` for parent, it won't re-render, but since prop has been changed Child will re-render.